# Sharing data between graphics and physics engine in the game?

Tags: c++, graphics, game-engine, physics-engine, 3d-engine

I'm writing a game engine that consists of a few modules. Two of them are the **graphics engine** and the **physics engine**.

**I wonder if it's a good solution to share data between them?**

Two ways (sharing or not) looks like that:

### Without sharing data

```
GraphicsModel{
    //some common for graphics and physics data like position

    //some only graphic data 
    //like textures and detailed model's vertices that physics doesn't need
};

PhysicsModel{
    //some common for graphics and physics data like position

    //some only physics data 
    //usually my physics data contains A LOT more information than graphics data
}

engine3D->createModel3D(...);
physicsEngine->createModel3D(...);

//connect graphics and physics data 
//e.g. update graphics model's position when physics model's position will change
```

I see two main problems:

1. A lot of redundant data (like two positions for both physics and graphics data)
2. Problem with updating data (I have to manually update graphics data when physics data changes)

### With sharing data

```
Model{
     //some common for graphics and physics data like position
};

GraphicModel : public Model{
    //some only graphics data 
    //like textures and detailed model's verticles that physics doesn't need
};

PhysicsModel : public Model{
     //some only physics data 
    //usually my physics data contains A LOT more informations than graphics data
}

model = engine3D->createModel3D(...);
physicsEngine->assignModel3D(&model); //will cast to 
//PhysicsModel for it's purposes??

//when physics changes anything (like position) in model 
//(which it treats like PhysicsModel), the position for graphics data 
//will change as well (because it's the same model)
```

Problems here:

1. `physicsEngine` cannot create new objects, just "assign" existing ones from engine3D (somehow it looks more anti-independent for me)
2. Casting data in assignModel3D function
3. `physicsEngine` and `graphicsEngine` must be careful - they cannot delete data when they don't need them (because the second one may need it). But it's a rare situation. Moreover, they can just delete the pointer, not the object. Or we can assume that `graphicsEngine` will delete objects, `physicsEngine` just pointers to them.

**Which way is better?**

Which will produce more problems in the future?

I like the second solution more, but I wonder why most graphics and physics engines prefer the first one (maybe because they normally make only graphics or only physics engine and somebody else connect them in the game?).

**Do they have any more hidden pros & cons?**

Comment: If you have a parent object for either of the graphics or physics models you could implement component based design and try writing something to the tune of `phy = parent->request("PhysicsModel")`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "assing"?

Comment: Quetzalcoatl - By assing I mean "inform physicsEngine that such an object was created and should be added to physicsEngine" (to monitor it's position, use it in calculations etc.). So physicsEngine should do with it everything that it normally do during creating new object (add to lists etc.) but without creating new one (treats like "new PhysicsModel" was executed outside the physicsEngine and make rest of actions from createPhysicsModel() for that particular model given as an pointer).

Comment: I would recommend you to ask such questions on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com - the people over there are much more specialized of design patterns optimized for game engines.

Comment: By "assing" did you mean "assign"?

Comment: @Noumenon yep, of course. I've just corrected it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowadays, more game engines adopts a component design (e.g. Unity, Unreal). In this kind of design, a `GameObject` is composed of a list of components. In your situation, there can be a `MeshComponent` and a `PhysicalComponent`, both attaching to a single game object.

For simplicity, you can put a world transform variable to the `GameObject`. During update phrase, `PhysicalComponent` outputs the world transform to that variable. During rendering, the `MeshComponent` reads that variable.

The rationale behind this design is to decouple between components. Neither `MeshComponent` nor `PhysicalComponent` knows each other. They just depends on a common interface. And it can be easier to extend the system by composition, than using single hierarchy of inheritance.

In a realistic scenario, however, you may need more sophisticated handling between physics/graphics synchronization. For example, the physics simulation may need to be run in fixed time step (e.g. 30Hz), while rendering need to be variable. And you may need to interpolate results from the output of physics engine. Some physics engine (e.g. Bullet) has direct support of this issue though.

Unity provided a good reference of their [Components](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/), which worth a look.